# C Compiler syntax error detection

Tags: c, compiler-construction

Coming from a beginner level programmer - does a C compiler build a concrete syntax tree for detecting errors like missing semicolons?

Or more generally, how does a C compiler detect syntax errors?

Comment: Yes we say it parse-tree/ or syntax tree, actually compiler generate abstract syntax tree to add semantic checks also (where each node stores attribute informations) for example invalid operand to an operator.

Comment: i read AST does n't include semicolons/parenthesis etc, then how it can check for valid c statement or not?? any other step by compiler before building AST??

Comment: If you learn compiler you come to know compiler is consists of many phases like Lexical, Syntax, Semantic, Code Generation, Optimization.. an possible error is associated with a phase. for example `int i = 10al;` is  lexical error as `al` is a invalid suffix, so not a valid token. `f(a, b` is syntax error because missing `)` in function call and `int a[10];`, `++a;` is semantic error as array names are constant you can't increment array name.

Comment: See which book you where reading may for example in Python (and also in Javascript) `;` are not need so it is not necessary that missing `;` will be an syntax error it depends on language.

Comment: Additionally How to respond error messages is (generally) not defined in language standards, It is up to compiler. Different compiler may respond differently for same error. It depends on what parsing technique they uses. Compiler writing would be much simpler if compiler has to translate only valid programs, but programs make mistakes so extra effort need to respond error detection and error recover that introduce complicity in compiler design.

Comment: I don't think compilers necessarily build a tree for the entire source file. For example, while it's processing the second function definition in a source file, the syntax information for the first function definition will likely have been discarded.

Answer (score 1):

> does a C compiler build a concrete syntax tree

Yes, or rather an 'abstract syntax tree', at least conceptually.

> for detecting errors like missing semicolons?

Not *for* detecting syntax errors; *after* detecting and removing syntax errors.

Syntax errors are detected *during* parsing, on encountering a token that isn't a valid continuation of the current state. It's a large subject. Don Knuth is writing a monster tome on it, and has been for 20 years ;-), but there are plenty already in existence.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, every compiler tries to build a parsing tree from the input files and generates a syntax error when it fails.

Anyway, in order for the compiler to figure out what's wrong exactly, a little bit more intelligence is required. For example, the compiler may attemptively insert a semicolon where parsing breaks and see if that would fix the syntax error. If so, it may suggest that a semicolon is missing in the error message.

As a note, C syntax is well defined by the standard, while error messages like "missing semicolon" are a friendly addition of the compiler.